# Modify the print DATA in report

Tags: database, winforms, sql-server-2005, reporting

I want to print a certain data for my program, but every time I run the program it shows all the DATA instead of showing the specific DATA that I want to print. how can I do it? can anyone tell me a way to  ease my problem?

Is there a way to choose one DATA in my `DATABASE`? So that I can print it alone.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, Visual Basic Window Form Application, and my DB is in SQL SERVER 2005.
 and to show the DATA I used REPORT WIZARD.

Comment: Try creating a SQL Query with parameters/criterias so your data gets filtered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered the same problem before and I took some research. I think you should use 'Filtering and Parameterizing'

What [This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=psLVbNx0GtU)

This should help you.